# Foundry - Using tranforms verbs inmemory datastore to test incremental transforms

Tags: palantir-foundry

Im using the in-memory datastore approach to test incremental transform and im receiving the error below. Any idea what i might be doing wrong.

> def test_transformdata_incr(spark_session):
>
> ```
>     df_input = spark_session.createDataFrame([
>         (1, 'abc', 1000, '2022-08-01'),
>         (2, 'abc', 2000, '2022-08-02'),
>         (3, 'def', 2000, '2022-08-01')
>     ], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>     
>     df_expected = spark_session.createDataFrame([
>         ('abc', 3000, '2022-08-12 15:10:00'),
>         ('def', 2000, '2022-08-12 15:10:00')
>     ], ['b', 's_colc', 'ts'])
>     
>     transform_input = '/data/sampledata'
>     transform_output = '/data/sampledata_output'
>     
>     pipeline = Pipeline()
>     pipeline.add_transforms(compute)
>     store = InMemoryDatastore()
>     store.store_dataframe(transform_input, df_input)
>     runner = TransformRunner(pipeline, datastore=store)
>     df_output = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, transform_output)
>     
>     assert df_output.subtract(df_expected).count() == 0
>     assert df_expected.subtract(df_output).count() == 0
>     assert df_output.schema == df_expected.schema
> ```

Error:

> > ```
> >   df_output = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, transform_output)
> > ```
>
> myproject/tests/test_transformdata_incr.py:30:
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ../build/conda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transforms/verbs/testing/TransformRunner.py:74:
> in build_dataset
> self._build_dataset_recursive(spark_session, alias) ../build/conda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transforms/verbs/testing/TransformRunner.py:84:
> in _build_dataset_recursive
> self._build_derived(spark_session, alias) ../build/conda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transforms/verbs/testing/TransformRunner.py:107:
> in _build_derived
> transform.compute(**kwargs)
>
> ---
>
> self = <transforms.api._incremental._IncrementalCompute object at
> 0x7f1b6f9afd60> ctx =
> <transforms.verbs.testing.dummies.DummyTransformContext object at
> 0x7f1b6e85c790> transform_ios = {'output':
> <transforms.verbs.testing.dummies.DummyTransformOutput object at
> 0x7f1b6e85c730>, 'source_df':
> <transforms.verbs.testing.dummies.DummyTransformInput object at
> 0x7f1b6e85c070>} tinputs = {'source_df':
> <transforms.verbs.testing.dummies.DummyTransformInput object at
> 0x7f1b6e85c070>} toutputs = {} parameters = {'output':
> <transforms.verbs.testing.dummies.DummyTransformOutput object at
> 0x7f1b6e85c730>}
>
> ```
> def __call__(self, ctx=None, **transform_ios):  # pylint: disable=arguments-differ
>     """Run the computation by dynamically constructing IncrementalX objects from the general X objects.
>
>     TransformInput -> IncrementalTransformInput
>     TransformOutput -> IncrementalTransformOutput
>     TransformContext -> IncrementalTransformContext
>     """
>     tinputs = {
>         name: tio for name, tio in transform_ios.items()
>         if isinstance(tio, _transform.TransformInput) and not isinstance(tio, _transform.TransformOutput)
>     }
>     toutputs = {
>         name: tio for name, tio in transform_ios.items() if isinstance(tio, _transform.TransformOutput)
>     }
>
>     parameters = {
>         name: param for name, param in transform_ios.items()
>         if not isinstance(param, _transform.TransformInput) and not isinstance(param, _transform.TransformOutput)
>     }
> ```
>
> > ```
> >   foundry = list(toutputs.values())[0]._dfreader._foundry  # Kinda horrible, but we grab a foundry instance E       IndexError:
> > ```
>
> list index out of range
>
> ../build/conda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transforms/api/_incremental.py:169:
> IndexError

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work-around.
you can mock the decorator:

```
def _fake_incremental_decorator(trasnform_obj):
   DummyTransformContext.is_incremental = False
   return trasnform_obj
```

You can use then a context manager within the test to apply the mock:

```
with patch('transforms.api.incremental', return_value=_fake_incremental_decorator):
     
    pipeline.add_transforms(compute)
```